# PHP MySQL: Insert record with self-referencing lookup field but can't get past foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So i have the table **company** defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chkdcrm.company (
  company_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_de VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  parent_company INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (company_id),
  CONSTRAINT parent_company
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_company)
    REFERENCES chkdcrm.company (company_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And for the HTML-Form I have:

```
<?php
  $require_once '../conn.php';
  //...
  $parent_company="";
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    //codes...
  if ($_POST["parent_company"] == '') {
      $parent_company = 'NULL'; 
    }
    else {
      $parent_company = $_POST["parent_company"];
    }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO company (name_de, parent_company) VALUES (?, ?)";
  if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $param_name, $param_parent);
    $param_name = $name_de;
    $param_parent = $parent_company;
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $company_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

//HTML-Form...

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Parent company(if exists)</label>
    <br>
    <?php
      echo '<select name="parent_company">';
      echo '<option value=""></option>';
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT company_id, name_de FROM company ORDER BY name_de ASC");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<option value = "'.$row['company_id'].'">'.$row['name_de'].'</option>';
      }
      echo '</select>';
     ?>
  </div>
```

The goal is to select the parent company from the lookup field. But I can't figure out how to insert companies that doesn't have a parent company (i.e the parent_company = NULL). I get the error message: 
`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (chkdcrm.company, CONSTRAINT parent_company FOREIGN KEY (parent_company) REFERENCES company (company_id) ON DELETE SET NULL)`.

I think the problem is that since **company_id** is **int**, it doesn't accept NULL value. Therefore it's treated as an invalid insert. But how can I get around this problem? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Maybe build a "ghost" parent company and add it for the company with no parent?

Comment: @MickaelLeger This works for the HTML display, but the database still gonna show that it has a parent company that refers to the "ghost" parent company...

Comment: Well to keep the logic, when you want to display all company add a where condition to not select it ! But maybe there is something better for sure :)